# media recorder crashes when start

Tags: android, mediarecorder

i have a problem with media recorder. it cant be start and comes to activity thread. i cant find the problem. all permissions set.
thank you for help me:)

```
private void startCaptureVideo()
    {
        camera = getCameraInstance();
        //cameraPreview = new cameraPreview(this,camera);
        try {

            surfaceHolder =  selfImage.getHolder();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.lock();
        if(checkCameraHardware(this)) {
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "masterVideo"+System.currentTimeMillis());
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(selfImage.getWidth(), selfImage.getHeight());
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
               // mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaRecorder.start();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,":( :( :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```